# ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" generates misleading error messages

Tags: powershell

I've seen `New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application` around a lot looking for solutions that execute actions on other files. (In my case, installing fonts).

Although it works fine in interactive mode:

```
PS C:\> New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application'

Application        Parent
-----------        ------
System.__ComObject System.__ComObject
```

It failed to do so inside my PowerShell script:

```
function Install-Font {
   Param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      [System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]]
      $Files
   )
   $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
   echo "Shell: " $shell
   echo "Files: " $Files
   $Files | ForEach-Object {
      $Fonts = $shell.NameSpace($_.Directory.Name)
      $font = $Fonts.ParseName($_.Name)
      $font.InvokeVerb("Install")
   }
}

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Get-ChildItem $env:TEMP\FiraCode\ttf -Filter *.ttf -File | Install-Font
```

Outputs:

```
PS C:\Users\villasv\Code\WindowsProSetup> .\testB.ps1
Shell:

ForEach-Object : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\villasv\Code\WindowsProSetup\testB.ps1:10 char:13
+    $Files | ForEach-Object {
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ForEach-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Observe that `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` is acting very suspiciously. If I remove it, the errors are completely different:

```
PS C:\Users\villasv\Code\WindowsProSetup> .\testB.ps1
Shell:

Application        Parent
-----------        ------
System.__ComObject System.__ComObject
Files:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\villasv\Code\WindowsProSetup\testB.ps1:12 char:7
+       $font = $Fonts.ParseName($_.Name)
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\villasv\Code\WindowsProSetup\testB.ps1:13 char:7
+       $font.InvokeVerb("Install")
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

After debugging the script, I can confirm that the shell is being correctly instantiated and the `$Files` parameter is also not null.

The true error is the one shown when I remove the `ErrorActionPreference`. To me, this can only mean that this setting is messing up with the stdout printing, code analysis or something similar.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Works fine for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce either, on Windows 7 / PowerShell 5.0.10586.117

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with a MWE, I'll update ASAP. Still, any idea on what could cause this?

Comment: Are you running the script interactively or through e.g. Task Scheduler or a service?

Comment: I'm invoking interactively. But the code is dot sourced all around, which is a mess.

Comment: There it is, now I can reproduce it in a single script. I'm trying to understand why adding `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` would cause the error message to differ so much.

Comment: @VillasV With `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` original error bubble up as exception to `ForEach-Object` and rethrowed here. You should use `$Error[1]` to see original error, not one rethrowed by `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

Comment: @PetSerAl So you're saying that `ForEach-Object` automatically catches the exception and rethrow it? That's very unintuitive to me. I'm not doing any error handling, I just expected it to at least give a stacktrace if it's going to rethrow things. If that's expected behavior, I'll gladly accept that as an answer. (maybe with some further comments on why/what for this behavior)

Comment: @VillasV I was not correct about rethrow part. `ForEach-Object` does not catch exception, and when exception leave `ForEach-Object` scope, then PowerShell record it as `ForEach-Object` failure, thus error point to `ForEach-Object`. Original exception (with correct error position and callstack) is preserved in `InnerException` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is clear. 
The frist error you get is not critical. It is the one on the echo of "shell : " $shell
You need at least something like "shell : $shell" or "shell : " + $shell
Same for $file

The second one is a critical one.
You try to send null to the foreach-object.

So if you do not  adjust the default error behavior. 
He will swallow the first error and fail on the seccond one.

By the way try using write-host instead of echo.
If you think like powershell you will be like powershell.

Comment: The first one is not an error (although it's poorly done), it will just `echo` separately. The second is also not the error, because just like I've said, `$Files` is not null.